# Disabling the Ubntu desktop enviourment

Tags: 13.04, unity-dash, desktop-environments

I have Ubuntu 13.04 setup I Want to disable the feature(Dash , Default search, left click and right click option on desktop) of Ubuntu desktop environment .
I found these commands for disabling right click

To disable right click for just desktop :

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 99"
```

To apply for system wide:

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 0 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

are there commands to disable dash and left click functionality too..??

Comment: WHy dont you just use an xfce derivative instead?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a way out of it i am running Ubuntu in gnome-shell environment .
In Gnome-shell all the unity facilities as dashboard etc, are not present .
also u can costomize the pane menu which is more or less like full filing my requirement.

for disabling right click i am using above command .